# filter out mysql duplicate record in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, wamp

Guys urgent help needed!

Well I ve a mysql database which has more than 158,000 records and there are some duplicate datas in it. I wish to list these duplicate datas 
To be more clear what exactly I'm looking for is:

the mysql table name is **postal**. and the columns are id, street, zipcode, locality and city

1. id:1, zipcode: 123456, street: street1,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
2. id:2, zipcode: 123456, street: street2,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
3. id:3, zipcode: 123456, street: street3,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
4. id:4, zipcode: 123457, street: street4,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
5. id:5, zipcode: 123458, street: street5,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
6. id:6, zipcode: 166666, street: street6,  locality: locality26, city: cityDE
7. id:7, zipcode: 177777, street: street7,  locality: locality38, city: cityEF

These values are allowed! This is a rough sketch of the datas that have been entered into mysql db table: **postal**

*Same* **zipcodes**(eg: id=1,2,3) will have different **street** values but **only one locality name** is allowed for them. Also *different* **zipcodes**(eg: id=3,4,5) may or may not have different **locality**. Please don't get much confused about this.
The problem I am facing is, I have found some record like these:

1. id:11, zipcode: 111111, street: street1,  locality: locality1, city: cityA
2. id:25, zipcode: 111111, street: street2,  locality: locality2, city: cityA
3. id:56, zipcode: 111111, street: street3,  locality: locality3, city: cityA

You can notice that *same* **zipcode**(eg: id=11,25,56) is having entirely different **locality** values, which is not allowed. Only one locality value is permissible for same zipcode.

Kindly suggest me the sql query string for filtering out zipcode containing different locality values. Please not there are more than 150,000 records.

NB: I am not asking for sql query which can sort the values according to pincode, I am looking for a way to find **zipcode** having different **locality** values.

Comment: Calm down. Those exclamation marks are making me nervous. 150,000 records are not really that big for a database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    postal.*
FROM 
    postal 
GROUP BY 
    zipcode
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT(locality)) > 1
```

Comment: I am not asking for sql query which can sort the values according to pincode, I am looking for a way to find zipcodes containing different locality values

Comment: bhai, this one is just giving me just one result that too displaying localities with same zipcode. I need a list which displays localities with different codes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,locality,zipcode,locality,city
FROM postal t1
WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT id,locality,zipcode,locality,city
FROM postal t2
WHERE t2.id <> t1.id
AND t2.zipcode = t1.zipcode
AND t2.locality != t1.locality
)
LIMIT 0,30
```

helped me to sort this one out.! now its working!